# how to change the text size in the title with html

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change the size of text in a h4 title. I want all letters to be capital but some to be smaller than others.  Basically change the text size withing the h3 tags.  Thanks so much for any help..

Comment: Have you tried using span elements inside your h3 tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I believe what you are looking for is called Small Caps.

Try this:

```css
    h4 {
      font-variant: small-caps;
    }
```

```html
<h4>This is Small Capped</h4>
<p>This is regular text.</p>
```

For More Info:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-variant/

Comment: thank you so much.  This is so much simpler than the other ways

Comment: You're welcome! Just so you are aware though, if a font is not specifically a small cap font (as in, designed with small caps in the first place) then making it a small cap font looks a little wonky and is considered bad form in the design community. It ends up making the capital letters look bold in comparison to others. You can find many small cap fonts with the letters SC after their name.

Comment: alright will keeep that in mind thanks so much! Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text size either in CSS or with the style attribute.

```
<h3 style="font-size:50px">The H3 Title</h3>
```

In CSS:

```
h3 {
   font-size:50px;
}
```

If you want to size parts of your title, use strong.

```
<h3 style="font-size:50px"><strong style="font-size:25px">The</strong> H3 Title</h3>
```

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
#h3Strong {
  font-size: 25px;
}
#h4Strong {
  font-size: 20px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<h3><strong id="h3Strong">The</strong> H3 Title</h3>
<h4><strong id="h4Strong">The</strong> H4 Title</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
.c2{
    font-size:2em!important;
}
.span{
    font-size:1em;
}
h3{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

And the html :

```
<h3>
    <span class="c2">1</span>
    <span>2</span>
</h3>
```

```css
.c2{
    font-size:2em!important;
}
.span{
    font-size:1em;
}

h3{
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h3>
    <span class="c2">a</span>
    <span>b</span>
</h3>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7fye5nc/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<h4>this is <small>where the title goes</small></h4>

<style>

h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h4 small {
    font-size: .75em;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To increase the font size, use the CSS [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) property.

To make all text uppercase, use the CSS [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) property.

```css
.big {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h3>Hello World!</h3>
<h3 class="big">Foo Bar!</h3>
```